# calculate Lie algebra valued form

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Suppose we have two differential form $\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ with Lie algebra value.

We write this two forms as $g \otimes \phi$ and $h \otimes \tau$, here $g,h$ denote the elements in lie algebra and $\phi ,\tau$ denote the differential forms.Then how to calculate $g \otimes \phi \wedge h \otimes \tau$ ?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: For pure forms it's just $(g \otimes \phi) \wedge (h \otimes \tau) = [g ,h] \otimes (\phi \wedge \tau)$

Comment: @SebastianSchulz I think, typically, there is a sign that comes in

Comment: (because one is passing the $h$ past the $\phi$)

Comment: There's an annoying sign if you want to define it on the whole space of Lie algebra valued forms. But the above is the standard definition on pure forms, which you can then extend bilinearly, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra-valued_differential_form#Wedge_product

Comment: Some authors use $\wedge$ to refer to the map $\Omega^k(M,\mathfrak{g})\to\Omega^l(M,\mathfrak{h})\to\Omega^{k+l}(M,\mathfrak{g}\otimes\mathfrak{h})$, reserving $[\ \wedge\ ]$ or $[\ ,\ ]$ for the operation defined in the comments above. Which operation are you interested in?

Comment: @SebastianSchulz thanks